# How to group by time slot between two dates

Tags: mysql

I have a question that make me feel silly !
I have to do some stats on the use of my apps.

I have a table call : customer_point

```
id  int(11)  auto_increment              
id_customer  int(11)
type_point  int(11)   
date  timestamp CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I want to make this request for the entire month (with a row for each night ;) ) :

```
SELECT COUNT( id_customer ) , type_point, date(date)
FROM customer_point  
WHERE date BETWEEN "2014-06-01 20:00:00" AND "2014-06-02 10:00:00"
GROUP BY type_point, date;
```

I nearly sure that i miss a crusial point but i can't find witch one.

Thank you very much for reading me !
Bye,

edit :

Sample :

```
INSERT INTO `customer_point` ( `id` , `id_customer` , `type_point`, `date` ) 
VALUES ( '', '15', '1', '2014-06-01 22:50:00'), ( '', '15', '1',  '2014-06-01 23:52:00'), ( '', '15', '1', '2014-06-02 9:50:00'), ( '', '15', '1', '2014-06-30 22:50:00'), ( '', '15', '1',  '2014-06-30 23:52:00'), ( '', '15', '1', '2014-07-01 02:50:00', ( '', '15', '1', '2014-07-01 09:50:00');
```

result :

```
1, 3, 2014-06-01
1, 4, 2014-06-30
```

I hope this will help everbody to understand my probleme :/

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, could you provide some sample data and desired result ?

Comment: `"2014-06-01 20:00:00" AND "2014-06-02 10:00:00"` - the date seems to be only between 1st and 2nd day of June.

Comment: 3 1 2014-06-04 
    2 1 2014-06-10 
    1 1 2014-06-14 
    6 1 2014-06-15 
    7 1 2014-06-17

Comment: I think need to change the timezone. This seems to be a timezone problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want coutns of the actual data, check the date is within the range you are interested in and that the time is at night (ie, greater than 8pm or less than 10am, if would seem from your SQL):-

```
SELECT type_point, date(customer_point.date) AS aDate, COUNT( id_customer )
FROM customer_point  
WHERE DATE(customer_point.date) BETWEEN "2014-06-01" AND "2014-06-30"
AND TIME(customer_point.date) >= '20:00:00' OR TIME(customer_point.date) <= '10:00:00'
GROUP BY type_point, aDate;
```

To get a row per day, irrespective of whether there is any data that day(ie, a count of zero it no data) then you need to generate a list of dates and then LEFT JOIN your data to it.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT sub0.aDate, type_point, COUNT( id_customer )
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-06-01', INTERVAL units.i + tens.i * 10 DAY) AS aDate
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) tens
) sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_point  
ON sub0.aDate = date(customer_point.date)
WHERE sub0.aDate BETWEEN "2014-06-01" AND "2014-06-30"
GROUP BY sub0.aDate, type_point;
```

You would also probably need to generate a list of type_point values.

EDIT - to go with the updated question, can you just subtract 10 hours from the date / time. So 10am on the 1st July becomes midnight on the 30th June?

```
SELECT type_point, date(DATE_ADD(customer_point.date, INTERVAL -10 HOUR)) AS aDate, COUNT( id_customer )
FROM customer_point  
WHERE DATE(DATE_ADD(customer_point.date, INTERVAL -10 HOUR)) BETWEEN "2014-06-01" AND "2014-06-30"
AND TIME(customer_point.date) >= '20:00:00' OR TIME(customer_point.date) <= '10:00:00'
GROUP BY type_point, aDate;
```

SQL fiddle:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddc95/2

The issue with this is whether items from before 10am on the 1st of June count as dates for May or for June?

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

The fact is the star of my month is the 1st at 22:00:00 et the end is the 1st of next month at 10:00:00 :/ So with your answer i will not take count of last night of my month :/

For the day fact, i made a mistake, i don't need to make a day stat at all :/

Comment: I am confused. Do you want a count of all the id_customer, or only the ones with a date / time between 22:00 and 10:00?  Do you need this broken down by date? Could you modiy your original question and put a bit of sample data and what you would like output from it?

Comment: I add sample and the result i hope to have. I'm not sure if my question is that clear :/

Comment: On the first of the month before 10:00:01 it count for previous month et after 21:59:59 it count for present month.

The issue with this is whether items from before 10am on the 1st of June count as dates for May or for June? May :)

Comment: That should do it, although you might want to subtract 10 hours and 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Using mysql you even could do

```
WHERE date LIKE "2014-06-%"
```

Edit: You need exactly from 20:00 and then you have to take in account the first day of the next mounth until the 22:00...

Ok, then just substract those 20 hours to the date:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(column, INTERVAL 20 HOUR)....
```

Finally:

```
SELECT COUNT( id_customer ) , type_point, DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 20 HOUR) as mydate
FROM customer_point  
WHERE mydate LIKE "2014-06-%"
GROUP BY type_point, date;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

The fact is the star of my month is the 1st at 22:00:00 et the end is the 1st of next month at 10:00:00 :/ So with your answer i will not take count of last night of my month :/